# Laravel link to another section on different pages

Tags: css, laravel-5

I made a dropdown nav-bar, I want to link the dropdown menu to a different section on a different blade.
What I want to know is how to link section of another blade into href="{{ route('somepage')}}" like I want to go to somepage.blade.php   and in my dropdown menu, I want to click dropdown submenu to go to directly to the section I want.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create include folder in views folder then you can create file in include folder after that you can write the code of navbar in it ..like this :

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('dashboard')}}">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="{{ route('account') }}">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
</header>
```

then you can do something like import it in any view you want ...like it:

```
<body>
       @include('includes.header') 
      <div class="container">
          @yield('content')
      </div>

     <!-- First include jquery js -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Then include bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I asked, but thanks! What I want to know is how to link section of another blade into href="{{ route('somepage')}}" like I want to go to somepage.blade.php <div id="section 5"> </div> and in my dropdown menu, I want to click dropdown submenu to go to directly to the section I want.

Comment: @ZW723 im sorry i didn't understand your question ...you can do it with this 
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('dashboard')}}">Brand</a> in your div ,then in your web.php in routes folder you can put this :
Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
]);
then in your controller you should put this:
public function getDashboard()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('dashboard', [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }